# Ruby on Rails : MySQL client library issue when trying to create database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application which is running on Rails 3.2.8 and Ruby 1.9.3.I am also using Mysql server as database.

When I run rake db:migrate, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the
client library is 5.5.34.
C:/Rails SampleApps/MyAppName/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Rails SampleApps/MyAppName/Rakefile:5:in `require'
C:/Rails SampleApps/MyAppName/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How do I solve this issue?

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: What is the version of `mysql2` gem which you are using ?

Comment: i am using mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32 and mysql Server version 5.5.

Comment: Are you using 32-bit Windows OS because the gem `mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32` is for windows 32-bit OS ?

Comment: i am using windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.But i installed 32-bit version of Mysql Server

Comment: Can you plz try out the two options which I have posted as answer and if it doesnot solves your issue then you should install the 64-bit version of MySQL server, follows the same steps mentioned in answer and let me know if you face any more issue ?

Comment: second option works for me.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using windows, you have two options to solve this :

Either use `2.8.1` version of `mysql` gem by writing

```
gem 'mysql', '2.8.1' #in your gemfile
```

run

```
bundle install
```

OR

Simply use `mysql2` gem

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

and put the `libmysql.dll` file in installed `MySQL` bin directory with the one which you can get from the below link  in location `lib/libmysql.dll` from

http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick

Answer (score 1):

gem 'mysql2' ## gemfile

rm Gemfile.lock

bundle install

rake db:drop && rake db:create